# Both reset_default_graph and tensorflow.compat have version difference to use tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I had some issues about using
'''
tensorflow.reset_default_graph
'''
,so I tried to downgrade the tensorflow version to 1.4.
And I had problem about:
'''
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'
'''
.
The problem about reset_default_graph was in the version of tensorflow 2.0, and the version about tensorflow.compat was 1.4.

Comment: Can you upgrade tensorflow from `1.4` to `1.15` and try ? In `TF 2.x`, did you tried use of  `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph` instead of `reset_default_graph` ?

Comment: not still working though

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I finished it by disabling it.

Comment: Which one you have disabled? Can you brief for the benefit of community?

Comment: tensorflow.compat.v1.reset_default_graph(),
tensorflow.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() are used to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments

> In TF 2.x, you can use `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()` instead of
> `reset_default_graph()`.
>
> After disabling eager execution using
> `tensorflow.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` has resolved the
> issue.